# What grammar pattern is used here and what does it mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This excerpt is from *[The Invisible Man](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/5230)* by H.G. Wells. I can't figure out the italicized part. The excerpt follows:

> "But they take long enough to get well, don't they? ... There was my sister's son, Tom, jest cut his arm with a scythe, tumbled on it in the 'ayfield, and, bless me! he was three months tied up sir. You'd hardly believe it. It's regular given me a dread of a scythe, sir."
>
> "I can quite understand that," said the visitor.
>
> "He was afraid, one time, that he'd have to have an op'ration—he was that bad, sir."
>
> The visitor laughed abruptly, a bark of a laugh that he seemed to bite and kill in his mouth. "Was he?" he said.
>
> "He was, sir. *And no laughing matter to them as had the doing for him, as I had—my sister being took up with her little ones so much.* There was bandages to do, sir, and bandages to undo. So that if I may make so bold as to say it, sir—"
>
> "Will you get me some matches?" said the visitor, quite abruptly. "My pipe is out."

Comment: I don't see an italicized part.

Comment: @rogermue See the second last paragraph.

Answer (score 3):

> And no laughing matter to them as had the doing for him, as I had—my sister being took up with her little ones so much

There may well be a better 'translation' or gloss but this is the gist of the sentence:

> And it was no laughing matter for those of us who had all the looking after him to do, like I had - what with my sister being so wrapped up in looking after the kids.

Here's a kind of step by step gloss:

> And [it was] no laughing matter for those [/*them*] who had the doing [all his stuff] for him [to do], like I had [to] - with my sister being taken [/*took*] up with her children [*little ones*] so much.

The section *them as had the doing for him* is a type of relative clause. In modern standard English, we prefer not to have an accusative pronoun like *them* as an antecedent for a relative clause - hence *those* in the modern gloss above. The relative clause is fronted by *as* instead of a modern subordinator such as *that* or a relative pronoun such as *who*.

Comment: A nice answer, Araucaria! Should it really be "what with my sister" and not "that with my sister", I wonder. I first thought it a typo but now am unsure.

Comment: @CopperKettle Thanks :) We have a kind of fixed phrase *what (tiny pause) with*. It means some thing like *considering* or *because of*, it gives an idea of there being lots of things to consider. ***It was a bit difficult to understand what she was saying, what with all the noise,  and commotion and everything ....***

Comment: @Kaptan Singh - This is not so much grammar but rendering of a certain kind of very colloquial speech. Typical is "them as" instead of  "those  who",